# Static member and lock

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a class with a static member:

```
static MayClass s_member;
```

It can be accessed by multiple threads.
Should I use a static lock object for it?

Comment: Question is vague, *accessed by multiple threads* can mean anything, reading, writing, calling methods, mutating, overwriting the field itself. be precise in your question. then you'll get expected answer without assumptions.

Comment: If you need to ask then the answer is probably "yes".  Just apply the common sense rule: a lock is required when one thread can read a variable and another can write it.  This includes the s_member reference itself *as well as* the members of MayClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to prevent concurrent access, then you need to protect with a lock. If concurrent access presents no problems, there is no need for a lock.

Only with knowledge of what you do with the member can answer this one way or another. Do the threads which access concurrently only ever read? If so, then you likely do not need a lock. Otherwise, if you are writing to shared data, then a lock would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that MayClass is not written to be thread-safe, then, yes, you should protect access to it via a lock.